# How to send a lot of variables to a generic function?

Tags: c, unit-testing, void-pointers

I have a function `f`, defined as following:

```
struct s {
    void *data;
    struct s *next;
};

void
f(struct s **p, void *q)
{
    /* ... */
}

void *
g(struct s **p)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

I have to test these functions, using a lot of different arguments. But pointers to `void` can contain only an object address, right ? So how can I automate operations as following, without using temporary variable (or maybe in a macro).

```
f(p, 2);
f(p, 'c');
f(p, 3.14);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way around of a temporary variable (well, you can use a static variable, it sure isn't temporary!) because you need an address, thus you need a (non-register) variable.

However, that doesn't mean you need additinal lines of code: you can use a typed initializer (as of C99):

```
f(p, &(int){2});
f(p, &(double){3.14});
```

However, the function (as you have defined it) has no way of knowing how big an object you have just passed to it, and it *must not* just store the pointer value because it's a pointer to a *very* temporary variable.

(Integers can be converted to pointers and back again with some restrictions but you have to check your implementation for details.)

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this thread example which accepts arguments similar way:

```
_beginthread( Bounce, 0, (void *) (structure_of_whatever_variables)  );
                            ^
                            |
                            |
                       This is the parameter of function Bounce
```

[This is source of above example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Is it a standard way ? Why does the `inptr_t` type exists if so ?

Comment: Maybe its about naming issues to make it easier understanding

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of the test variables and make a for loop to call it on by one. That way you will be able to send the address directly maybe something like that should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfTestCases; i++)
{
    f(p, &pArrOfTestCases[i]);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That's a solution, but I can't use variable of different types in a array, isn't it ? Thanks anyway.